# How to convert GDI bitmap to GDI+ Bitmap, DrawImage?

Tags: c++, bitmap, gdi+, gdi

I'm converting a C++ pgm from GDI to GDI+, in order to take advantage of some new features in GDI+. But I'm running into a strange problem: the GDI+ drawn image appears larger by a factor of ~1.3, and in a slightly different position on the screen.

This is the code in GDI, which works as expected--it copies a rectangle from the bitmap to the screen, at the same size as it is in the original bitmap. I want to know how to make GDI+ do exactly the same thing.

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
HANDLE hDCMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
HANDLE hBitmap = LoadImage(NULL, L"C:\\MyBitmap.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
HANDLE hSelect = SelectObject(hDCMem, hBitmap);

// In OnPaint:
// pt is the destination, in screen pixels  px,py are the position in the source bitmap  w and h are the size of the source and destination rectangles
DWORD rop = SRCCOPY;
bool ok = BitBlt(hdc, pt.x,pt.y, w, h, hDCMem, px, py, rop);
```

This is the code in GDI+ that I expected to do the same thing, but it does not. Even though the parameters of `DrawImage` are the same as those of GDI's `BitBlt`, I get a different result.

```
GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
Status gdiStatus=GdiplusStartup(&GDIPlusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL); // GDI+ version is 1

// Get the bitmap
Bitmap *tBitmap;
tBitmap = new Bitmap(L"C:\\MyBitmap.bmp");
Status st = tilesBitmap->GetLastStatus(); // ok

// Display part of the image
In OnPaint:
Graphics graphics(hdc);
// pt is the destination, in screen pixels  px,py are the position in the source bitmap  w and h are the size of the source and destination rectangles
Status st = graphics.DrawImage(tBitmap, (int)pt.x, (int)pt.y, px, py, w, h, UnitPixel);
```

If I change `UnitPixel` to `UnitDisplay`, I get an invalid parameter error from `DrawImage`.

Comment: All the comments for this Q have disappeared. To summarize them, the compositing mode is already `CompositingModeSourceOver`, by "parameters the same", I am referring to the positions and sizes. Since the GDI+ size is 4/3 the GDI size in both x and y, it may be a bitmap incompatibility. GDI+ bitmap is `ImageFormatBMP`, `PixelFormat24bppRGB`, flags `ImageFlagsReadOnly | ImageFlagsHasRealPixelSize | ImageFlagsHasRealDPI | ImageFlagsColorSpaceRGB`, size 1024 x 1162 = size of original bitmap file in Paint.

Comment: The bitmap resolution is 72.0089951 dots/in, while `graphics.GetDpiX()` shows 96 dots/in. Since 96/72=4/3, this is probably causing the unwanted magnification. So how do I correct this? I tried `graphics.SetPageScale(72.0089951/96)`, but this has no effect.